# Stripe - Create Customer and add to a plan with trial period

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm able to create a customer and add it to a subscription plan; following code works:

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_tz7AKV73RPCd7p**********");

// create Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => $email,
    "plan" => $plan_id,
    "source" => $token,
    "metadata" => array(
        "nome" => $name,
        "tel" => $tel,
        "indirizzo" => $indirizzo,
        "città" => $address_city,
        "provincia" => $address_state,
        "cap" => $address_zip
    ),
));
```

Then if I add a `trial_period_days" => 30` option, I get the following error:

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest): Received
>   unknown parameter: trial_period_days

I added it to the option hash as follow:

```
// create Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => $email,
    "plan" => $plan_id,
    "trial_period_days" => 30,
    "source" => $token,
    "metadata" => array(
        "nome" => $name,
        "tel" => $tel,
        "indirizzo" => $indirizzo,
        "città" => $address_city,
        "provincia" => $address_state,
        "cap" => $address_zip
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I got it; `trial_period_days` is an argument that should be used during `Subscription` creation, so I edited my code as follow:

```
// create Customer
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    "email" => $email,
    "source" => $token,
    "metadata" => array(
        "nome" => $name,
        "tel" => $tel,
        "indirizzo" => $indirizzo,
        "città" => $address_city,
        "provincia" => $address_state,
        "cap" => $address_zip
    ),
));

// associate Customer to the Plan
\Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    "customer" => $customer,
    "plan" => $plan_id,
    "trial_period_days" => 30,
));
```